# How to display bullet points in a list inside of a table in Java with itext?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I´m trying to add a list to a table cell but there are no bullet points. It works well when I add the same list to the document directly. What can I do to make the bullets appear?

```
Phrase p = new Phrase();

String html = "<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>";
ArrayList objects = HTMLWorker.parseToList(new StringReader(html, null);

for (int k = 0; k < objects.size(); ++k) {
 p.add((Element) objects.get(k));
}


// no bullet points
table.addCell(new PdfPCell(p));

// works
document.add(p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i may be wrong, but wouldn't using directmy the list (as the following code) work ?

```
List objects = HTMLWorker.parseToList(new StringReader(html, null);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(objects); 
table.addCell(cell);
```

regards